# How to properly query for a Constructor with an argument that is generic

Tags: java, reflection

I need to acquire the Constructor of a class at runtime using reflection instead of direct access. For simple types, this is trivial:

```
public class MyType {
    public MyType(String a, Integer b, Long c) {}
}

Constructor constructor = MyType.class.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.class, Long.class);
```

But if the class uses generics as part of its arguments, it's not clear what I should put:

```
public class MyType {
    public MyType(Set<String> a, Integer b, List<Long> c) {}
}

Constructor constructor = MyType.class.getConstructor(Set<String>.class /*Doesn't compile*/, Integer.class, List<Long>.class /*doesn't compile*/);
```

I can write something like `MyType.class.getConstructor(Set.class, Integer.class, List.class);` but it's not clear that that will achieve the behavior I want. What's the correct way to write this kind of code?

Comment: It would be rawtyped, so `Set.class`, etc. Those generic types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: You have to use `Set.class`, `List.class` etc. It doesn't matter that you don't have the generic type, since you can't have two constructors with parameters having the same erasure.

Comment: *it's not clear that that will achieve the behavior I want.* Why isn't it clear? Have you tested it? Did it work?

Comment: @shmosel I'm working with a build system that takes a long time to perform each build. Trial & Error is a lengthy, arduous process for me.

Comment: You don't have to use your build system. You can run a standalone test, e.g. http://ideone.com/JIkT5K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic information is not part of the information that is used by the `getConstructor` method. The call you denoted (`Set.class, ...`) is correct, as it resembles the information available at runtime.

As noted by Andy Turner, you can only have one constructor with this type - even if you try to use different generic arguments for a second constructor in your source code.

If you're curious, you can have a look at the bytecode using `javap`:

```
$ javap -private -c MyType
Compiled from "MyType.java"
public class MyType {
  public MyType(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Long);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

Comment: It's not true that generic type information isn't present in the bytecode: the compiler has to know that the parameter must be a `Set<Long>`, rather than a `Set<AnythingElse>`, and it finds this from the bytecode. It's that the generics aren't present *at runtime*.

Comment: No, that's not the case. Why do you think so?

Comment: how are you able to type-safely use generic methods for classes where you don't have the source, only a `.class` file?

Comment: You're right, there is some information which indeed is used by the compiler. I'll correct my response.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to acquire the constructor you need using reflections, but in this case is more complicated that it seems. You must check all the constructors of the class and all their parameters. Something like this:

```
public Constructor getConstructor() {
    Constructor constructor = null;
    Constructor<?>[] constructors = MyType.class.getConstructors();
    for(Constructor constructor1 : constructors) {
        Type[] types = constructor1.getGenericParameterTypes();
        if(types.length == 3) {
            if(types[0] instanceof ParameterizedType
                    && types[1].equals(Integer.class)
                    && types[2] instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                ParameterizedType type0 = (ParameterizedType) types[0];
                ParameterizedType type2 = (ParameterizedType) types[2];
                if(type0.getActualTypeArguments().length == 1 
                        && type0.getRawType().equals(Set.class)
                        && type0.getActualTypeArguments()[0].equals(String.class)
                        && type2.getActualTypeArguments().length == 1
                        && type2.getRawType().equals(List.class)
                        && type2.getActualTypeArguments()[0].equals(Long.class)) {
                    return constructor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, as noted by Andy Turner in the comments, you cannot create another constructor with the parameters with the same erasure `(Set.class, Integer.class, List.class)`.

Comment: So, given your acknowledgement of my comment, why do you need to do all of this, rather than just using `getConstructor(Set.class, Integer.class, List.class)`?

Comment: @AndyTurner As we do not know the real purpose of the code the OP is requesting, doing this you can be sure the constructor has the parameters and generics you need. Maybe he has some clases with constructors with the same erasure but with different generic types.

Comment: But if there is such a constructor in the class, you can get the only possible candidate by its erased parameter types: there's no need to loop over all constructors, check number of parameters etc.

Comment: For example, if you have a class with a constructor `MyType(Set<*Integer*> a, Integer b, List<Long> c)`, and you get the constructor with `getConstructor(Set.class, Integer.class, List.class)`, but you expect that constructor to be `MyType(Set<*String*> a, Integer b, List<Long> c)`, you will get an error when creating a new instance with `constructor.newInstance()`. My answer tries to avoid this searching for the right constructor and returning `null` if not found.

Comment: If there is only one constructor and you know for sure it is `MyType(Set<*String*> a, Integer b, List<Long> c)`, there is no need to do this, you are totally right. But if it is not the case, this could be a solution.